# gulp-sass slower with each compile

Tags: gulp, node-sass, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have a very simple *.scss compilation task with the use of npm and gulp 4.
It is watched by

```
const scssWatcher = watch(['scss/*.scss']);
scssWatcher.on('all', function(event, path){ compileSass(path); });
```

And the compileSass function just

```
gulp.src(path, {'base' : pathRoot + './scss'})
.pipe(sassInheritance({base: pathRoot + 'scss/'}))
.pipe(sass()).on('error', sass.logError)
.pipe(gulp.dest(pathRoot + 'css'));
```

The `sassInheritance` is `gulp-better-sass-inheritance` module, which makes sure that all files that include the updated file are also updated.

It works, but get slower with every compile.
Restarting the gulp task with this watcher works but is cumbersome.
I have found out that removing the `gulp-better-sass-inheritance` from the pipeline solves the issue.
I have had this working with gulp 3 with no problem.
There is this thread https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/467 with same behaving issue from 2016.

Anybody with the same experience? Any help?

Comment: gulp is dead. you should move on to grunt or webpack or something. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32651375

Comment: Alright... that is quite radical. But will look into that

Answer (score 0):

These watchers and live-re-loaders are full of bugs.
Just restart it automatically using the shell.

```
while true; do

     timeout 600 gulp run:live:watch whatever...
     sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: Nah... sorry, that is a terrible workaround causing more problems. I would rather downgarde to Gulp3